# Sql profiler - result in profiler : "Audit Login" and immediately after "Audit Logout" without running the query

Tags: sql-server, azure, profiler, azure-vm, kubernetes

I have a service running on an Azure kubernetes (AKS)
that is connecting to a DB running on a Virtual Machine (VM) on Azure.

There is a failure to run the service.

The result of SQL Profiler is:
[image]

There is only a login and a logout without running a query.

When running the service on a my local computer with the same connection string
the query run successfully.

[image]

Here is what i checked :

1. Network -Firewall and network issues for AKS.
   There is a subnet and a firewall exception for this service.
   I even ran a sqlcmd on the AKS and the query ran successfuly.
2. Connection string:
   Used the same connection string on both occasion,
   AKS - Failed
   Local Machine - succes.
   Here is my connection string format :
   Data Source=int-db-w1.dev.local\DEV1_INST;Initial Catalog={somecompany};User id={SomeUser};Password={somepassword}
3. Profiler -
   ran the profiler on two cases mentioned above.
   AKS - shows only Audit Login and Audit Logout.
   Local Machine - success.

I am now trying to send an error query to the database from the service,
to see if the profiler will show an error.

What more could i check?

Many Thanks

Comment: the VM is running on AZURE

Comment: Hey, an update for this problem. The problem is not on db side. I replaced the library named : "System.Data.SqlClient" in the code to : "Mircrosoft.Data.SqlClient". And added to the connection string : ;TrustServerCertificate=true. Seems do to the trick